# No sound on Chromebook with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. Sound options show up as 'Dummy Output'

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

This seems to be a very common problem. I have tried everything mentioned in the threads online, but nothing has worked.

I have an HP Chromebook 13 G1, and am running Ubuntu 20.04 and my output for `uname -srm` is `Linux 5.13.0-39-generic x86_64`.

I installed Ubuntu on the Chromebook by using MrChromebox, I'm not sure if that make a difference to anything. I know for sure the sound worked originally when ChromeOS was installed.

Here are some audio related outputs:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    DeviceName: Multimedia audio controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
```

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:276: no soundcards found...
```

```
$ pacmd list cars |egrep -i "output|active"

    argument: <sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'>
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
0 source output(s) available.
```

```
$ lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    DeviceName: Multimedia audio controller
```

I have followed the steps people suggest, but I'm not sure I'm following it correctly. For example, when people suggest to add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, I am meant to replace `snd-hda-intel` with `snd_soc_skl` right?

If anyone can give me some guidance on this, that would be wonderful.

EDIT:

The outputs I listed above were for a clean install of Ubuntu. After I change `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to add the lines

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

and I also added `blacklist snd_soc_skl` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Now my outputs are like this:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    DeviceName: Multimedia audio controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ aplay -l
  **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ pacmd list cars |egrep -i "output|active"
    argument: <sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'>
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    active profile: <off>
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
1 source output(s) available.
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.gnome.VolumeControl"
```

Comment: If you used your chromebook with a bluetooth speaker, you'd need to reconnect it to a bluetooth speaker. or else, pretty much you are stuck.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/1486278/124466) answer works on most chromebooks with Ubuntu 22.04+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue that modern Chromebooks (as of around 2015) do not maintain sound functionality when other versions of linux are installed.

The only exception I know of is [GalliumOS](https://galliumos.org/download). Which version of GalliumOS you need to install depends on the model of your Chromebook, but I found that Skylake allows the sound to work with the HP Chromebook 13 G1.

It's worth noting that bluetooth audio will work with other linux distros, so depending on your situation, it might be suitable to use Ubuntu with a bluetooth speaker, or headphones.