# How to install Chromebook audio drivers in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound, chromebook

Hello Ask Ubuntu users,

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Levono Ideapad 3 Chromebook. When installing it, I wasn't able to get the audio to work. I am assuming this is a driver issue. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this problem?

More computer specs (If needed):

4GB - Memory
Intel® Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz × 2 core - CPU
Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)

Comment: Since the chromebook does not have a lot of disk space, I would suggest you to remove snapd, and use APT packages instead. If you are using Firefox, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [audio-script](https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio) repository for Chromebooks, which works for Ubuntu 23.10 and later versions.

```
wget https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio/archive/ee4f0da7a9a60dfa1435722f9f65cc6334eb1735.zip
unzip ee4f0da7a9a60dfa1435722f9f65cc6334eb1735.zip -d chromebook-linux-audio
cd chromebook-linux-audio/chromebook-linux-audio-ee4f0da7a9a60dfa1435722f9f65cc6334eb1735/
./setup-audio
```

And reboot.

Your chromebook [is supported](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1udREts28cIrCL5tnPj3WpnOPOhWk76g3--tfWbtxi6Q/htmlview#gid=0).

Note that Ubuntu 22.04 is not well-supported by the audio script. Please use 23.10 or later versions instead.

---

Note that the latest version of Audio script does not support Ubuntu, and the developer recommends using another distro due to issues in Ubuntu, and also because the audio script requires a recent version of kernel.

However, I tried removing the condition to check for Ubuntu in the latest version of the audio script, and it worked perfectly in Ubuntu 24.04.