Lubuntu 24.04 install stuck at `Performing contextual processes' job` on Chromebook
I am trying to install Lubuntu 24.04 on an old Chromebook.
I selected a full install, plus Krita. Fast Internet connection.
I have not noticed "media checks" during the process, I might have missed them.
Problem: It is stuck on Performing contextual processes' job:

It has been like this for an hour. First I could move the mouse and check the Debug UI (which by the way did not show any task), but now it seems totally frozen, the mouse and keyboard have no effect anymore.
Question: Any idea how to investigate or fix the issue?
Hardware: HP Chromebook 14-ak050nr Intel BayTrail, flashed with firmware-util.sh UEFI Full ROM.

You didn't provide key specifics.. If you opted for a full install which includes multiple snap packages which need to be downloaded.. this can take awhile if you have slow internet (the installer will show no detail during this process; as it passed control to snap-seed processes... I liked opening a text terminal so I could monitor progress from there... aussie NBN is very slow so taking more than an hour happens; I'd thus not use full install options if not for QA testcases). Other install types are faster.. but you didn't specify.  Did you check that media checks completed?

@guiverc Thanks! I added the details I have knowledge of.

It seems that this Chromebook only has 16 GB of storage. Snaps consume a lot of space. Completely remove snapd with sudo apt purge --autoremove snapd, and replace snap apps with their apt counterparts to regain some storage. For example, the firefox apt package is a snap in disguise. Using Firefox PPA package would save a lot of space. The same is true for Chromium and Thunderbird.

Do the speakers+microphone+headphone jack work properly? If not, check out https://askubuntu.com/a/1486279/124466

In the recent versions of Ubuntu, most function key's work out of the box in Chromebooks. If some of them don't work (e.g. the fullscreen/lock key), check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451097/how-to-make-function-keys-work-on-a-chromebook-running-ubuntu

For me, selecting "Normal install" (without additional software) and unchecking the option to install updates helped prevent Lubuntu from getting stuck.

I encountered the same issue twice at 92%. Clicking on the log icon at the bottom right showed it stuck at 'snap-seed-glue'. After waiting 10 minutes, I unplugged and replugged the network cable a few times, and suddenly the installation completed 100%. Everything has been working fine since the reboot.
installation of kubuntu 24 stopped at 92%

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Another snap issue!


Hold the Power button at the top-right of the keyboard for 20 seconds
The computer reboots
The Lubuntu desktop environment starts, apparently functional. Web browsing works. Somehow my /var/log does not contain an installer directory but no drawback observed so far.

Any better fix is very welcome :-)

I'll suggest checking in /var/log/installer/ and check contents are as they should be... I suspect they're not.. ie. you aborted an install due to this process & the install was thus not completed.  You may have a fully-working system, and may not suffer any consequences.. but I'd check what was installed matches your install options (given you won't have install logs I suspect in that directory)

My /var/log does not contain an installer directory. :-O

Yep... the install was aborted due to power outage [you caused with power button].  Your system was never completely installed, only MOST of it was.  As stated in prior comment, you'll unlikely notice any consequences.. but given I suspect it was cancelled during a snap-seed or snap install process; check your snap system is good, and it all looks as it should be...  as install never completed.  Its likely a good install, just not perfect (at least from what little QA I did with aborted installed.. I never tested though for days/weeks/months, only 1-3 boots over mins-hour)

Your issue was likely a network problem....
I live in Australia, and our NBN (National Broadband Network) isn't exactly fast (by world standards), and thus many of my full installs took an hour+
I suspect you just had an installer issue, and your forced power outage by holding down the power button, caused the install process to end, as evidenced by the lack of contents in the /var/log/installer/ directory (the installer hadn't even got to creating that directory yet, let alone filling it with details).
Personally, if it was me, I'd do another install, and opt to do a NORMAL install (without the optional packages) as that install is much much faster, and far less likely to have problems with network issues (temporary or just aussie-slow).  You can always add those additional packages yourself post-install, with it much easier to see network issues (esp. if installed from terminal; but that's maybe just my preference)
In QA (Quality Assurance testing); I aborted some installs where you are, and then experimented to see if I had issues where I encountered a problem.  My testing  only involved 3-5 reboots, and usually less than an hour of subsequent testing post-install; which differs to an installed system you may actually use long-term for years!
ps: Due to your user-created power outage, you cannot check your logs to confirm your issue now, as they never got written to disk too; and checking what also didn't get done with your aborted install will be difficult.  I've made an assumption here that the issue was snap-seed-glue based purely on my QA installs with the aussie very slow NBN network experiences.

I didn't mention it in this answer.. but given I have slow internet (ISP has given me $5 refund the last couple of months due to slow speed)  but I usually when doing a FULL install open a text terminal & have it full screen on another monitor.. and have it monitor what the system is doing.. thus I can note what snap-seed-glue process is actually running.. and detect the process, as the installer doesn't actually see any progression on the called process thus cannot reflect that detail.
